# Efficient way to store hash: string values for quick lookup later? (Python)

Tags: python, hash

I'm trying to learn how brute-forcing of hashes works in Python. So far, I have a program that can generate every possible string of a certain length and hash them and save them to a file. But storing the generated hash table in plain text predictably takes up huge amounts of disk space (more than it should). I can't use `pickle` to store a dictionary to a file in binary because the entire table will now have to be stored in RAM. What are some efficient ways to store generated hashes and their corresponding strings to a file? I also need to look up the hashes without loading the whole thing into memory, but every time I try the script runs out of RAM and crashes.

TL;DR: What is the most efficient way to store key-value pairs of hashes to a file and look them up later?

Comment: You have discovered the reason why [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) exist.

Comment: @deceze Great, thank you.